# How to load a table with multiple zip files in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to upload data to a Snowflake table using a zip file containg multiple CSV files but I keep getting the following message:

> Unable to copy files into table. Found character '\u0098' instead of
>   field delimiter ',' File 'tes.zip', line 118, character 42 Row 110,
>   column "TEST"["CLIENT_USERNAME":1] If you would like to continue
>   loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as
>   'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more
>   information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a
>   SQL client.

If I skip the errors some data load but it is like snowflake is not properly opening the zip file and I just get some random characters like if the zip file was only opened with notepad.

I tried changing the File Format Compression Method to all the available ones: Auto, Gzip, Deflate, Raw Deflate, Bz2m Brotli, Zstd and None. Getting different error messages.

I know my Zip file is compressed using the standard Deflate compression method but when I select this type I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid data encountered during decompression for file: 'test.zip',compression type used: 'DEFLATE', cause: 'data error'
>   The "Auto" method sends the same error message as None

I also tried with zip files containing only one file and I get the same errors. The files that worked correctly were an uncompressed one (CSV) and one compressed using GZ but I need this to work using a zip file containing multiple CSVs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zip file is not a `DEFLATE` file, even though zip uses deflate. All the compression methods supported are single file compression methods. Where-as zip is a file archive, thus why it has many files, which would be similar to are tar.gz which is also not supported.

Thus you will ether need to uncompress your files yourself, in your S3 bucket, or alter your data export tool to conform.

[CREATE FILE FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html) help

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I understood zip files were supported by Snowflake when I read that help document but it was my misinterpretation. Hopefully, Snowflake will implement this functionality in the future, especially if the tool is mostly used for big data

Comment: we have gzip and bz2 files that are gigabytes, and we have thousands of them, not sure why "big data" means zip files

Comment: I didn't say zip files mean big data but is very common to store multiple files in zip files because sometimes it makes more sense to put together files like this. This is natively supported by many operative systems and the way I see it, not supporting zip files looks like a limitation of the tool. I understand the workaround and I also work with big individual gzip files but is not always the best option to store the files like that.

Comment: I guess I just really see it very differently.. If you have 1TB of compressed data, have 1 TB zip file makes no sense. It's a liability for transfers. Having you data in 500MB compressed sized chucks makes sense. If that data set is one CSV file (or any other format) it makes no sense (to me) to have it in N files inside that bundle, as each file has over head. if you have 500MB zip file that has 10K files inside, there is a huge overhead, if they are different data type, fine, but then you cannot load then in one process... Archives of tiny files doesn't map to at scale data processing.

Comment: It's more efficient in terms of space to compress the files individually rather than archive them using zip. https://dev.to/biellls/compression-clearing-the-confusion-on-zip-gzip-zlib-and-deflate-15g1