# Problem with CSV import from stage (curly brackets)

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to import csv file from stage and I am getting the error below

*Found character '}' instead of field delimiter ';'*

My data in csv. looks like

> 0911220;NULL;{{lorem.ipsum}};{{bla.bla}}

I don't know what to do. I don't have anything related to curly braces set in File Format. Should I change something there?

The file format is:

```
ALTER FILE FORMAT "RAW"."CRM".CSV_SEMICOLON_QUOTES_HEADER
    SET
    COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
    FIELD_DELIMITER = ';'
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
    SKIP_HEADER = 1
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'
    TRIM_SPACE = FALSE
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE
    ESCAPE = 'NONE'
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE'
    DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO'
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO'
    NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

And method of import:

```
copy into "..." ( list of columns ) 
    FROM @stage_name files = ( 'file.zip') file_format = ( 
        format_name=CSV_SEMICOLON_QUOTES_HEADER compression=GZIP);
```

Comment: What is the definition of your file format? How did you load file into stage and how did you try to import data from stage to table? Can you please share more details on exactly what commands you have tried?

Comment: Hi. This is my File Format definition

ALTER FILE FORMAT "RAW"."CRM".CSV_SEMICOLON_QUOTES_HEADER2 SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' FIELD_DELIMITER = ';' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 1 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N');


And additionally I added "compression=GZIP" because file is as GZIP
I tried import data through copy into.
Data was loaded by Amazon S3 Connection Manager from Visual Studio

Comment: And method of import


copy into "..."
(
list of columns
)
FROM @stage_name
files = ( 'file.zip')
file_format = ( format_name=CSV_SEMICOLON_QUOTES_HEADER compression=GZIP);

Comment: Please add all this information to your question so it is all in one place, rather than spread across comments

Comment: Using your sample data and DDL of the file format, I am able to load the data successfully, so I can't reproduce. Can you provide the full script from start to finish that can reproduce your issue? i.e. statement to create stage, file format, table, and how you put file into stage etc. Basically a standalone script that we can run from our end to test out.

Answer (score 1):

The file format name is wrong in the *copy into ...* query.

The file format you created is named as *CSV_SEMICOLON_QUOTES_HEADER2*. but in your query you wrote *..HEADER* instead of *..HEADER2*

Comment: It's mispelled here. In Snowflake name are the same

Comment: oho, then i don't think you can directly import .zip file like that. Supported formats are GZIP,  BZ2,  BROTLI, ZSTD, DEFLATE, RAW_DEFLATE. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58515136/17459198)

Comment: Sorry, this is GZIP. Generally other tables from the same system were loaded in exactly the same way. The problem is only here when we have "{" in the columns